# How can exp(x) be used in xcos?

Tags: scilab, control-theory, xcos

I'm trying to simulate K*e^(-θ*s)/(*s + 1), but xcos won't let me use exp(s) in my CLR block. Is there any way around that?
Also, how can I create an xcos model, without the value for the variables, and then assign the values through the editor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your transfer function represents a time delay θ in series with a first order system, use the following block to approximate the delay part : https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.0/en_US/TIME_DELAY.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean with "to simulate Ke^(-θs)/(*s + 1)", you may try or use
https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.0/en_US/scifunc_block_m.html
or
https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.0/en_US/EXPRESSION.html

The second part of your question is quite unclear as well.
Usually, *parameters* (not variables) are defined in the *context* of the diagram. If by *variables* you mean the input signal, then you must create and use a block among possible *sources* (see sources palette), that will deliver an output to be branched as input to your processing block.